# Receiving 404 Error with GitHub page when pushing repositories via GitHub Desktop

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying run this page on GitHub for an assignment, the intention is to have my algorithm pass the various JUnit tests, but my professor states that there's an error. When running via the Eclipse IDE console, I receive no issues running the tests, but they (and others) retrieve a 404 error when they try to access it through GitHub. The way I pushed the repository was via GitHub Desktop.

Link to the repo: https://github.com/NilesDobbs/Assignment7

I'm not sure where to identify the issue. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: the repo is not public?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the repository is private and that's why GitHub shows everyone except you 404. You see it because you are the owner of the repository.

Comment: Thanks, I now see the simple mistake on my end. I changed the repo to public now. To make sure, could you check to see if you're still retrieving the same error?

Comment: @NilesDobbs, you can use a private browser window to check links without authorization.